# Do sessions exist between NodeJS apps?

Tags: node.js, session, nginx

I'm building a platform at the moment that comprises of 2 sub-domains and the main site, for example:

```
example.com
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

These 3 apps are being run independently on a separate port and routed to via nginx.

Suppose `sub1.example.com` is in control of authentication and such. This is where the login would happen and set the session variables and generate the JWT. Would the session data be carried across from the one app to another? Would `sub2.example.com` be able to verify the session data?

How would I fix this?

Note: These apps were originally in one app, but are being separated now. The sessions are currently stored using Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session data won't be carried over to another sub-domain if you are not explicitly storing it in the centralised database or some storage mechanism which all subdomains can access.

Since you are using JWT, the authentication needs to be done on every sub domain if they are running on different servers/processes. You will just need to maintain the same secret key across.

For maintaining the session data, the simple step would be - 
If a user request comes on any sub-domain:

1. Authenticate the request using API key and JWT and store token in Redis if this is first time
2. Store your session data against that token in your persistent database

Now when another request comes from the same user with the JWT token, authenticate and see your db if session data is present against that token id and use them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If each of them is a different server, running a separate process of node.js, than you need some way to pass the session (or some sort of identifier) between them.
One way can be to use session header in your requests that will tell the other servers that you are already logged in.

Comment: With a single flag to say that you're logged in is okay, but the app uses API keys and JWT for authentication across the resources.